# Using killall command in php from a button click

Tags: php, node.js, terminal

I am looking to have a button on a webpage that I can use to kill all of the node processes that are running. I have got it working fine from terminal on Mac OS by using sudo killall node, but when i have tried to create a button from the website I am getting the error 'No matching processes belonging to you were found'.
My code is,

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['button'])) { exec('/usr/bin/ sudo killall node'); } ?>
 <form method="POST">
<p>
    <input type="hidden" name="button" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Stop">
</p>
</form>
```

I am guessing it is because I need to type in a password for sudo is why it won't work on the webpage. Is there a way around this or another option for doing it? thanks..

Comment: No, you don't need to type anything just set up the sudoers file correctly. But unless you put the command and its argument in a script you are allowing php to kill any process on your system.

Answer (score 0):

the user running php has probably not the privileges to run command with sudo ( or at least he can't enter the password )

if you really want to give php the right to run this command you have to figure out which user is running php (echo `whoami`;)
and then give him the right to run this command without asking for a password, run `sudo visudo` to edit sudo configuration

in it, add the following line at the end of the file:

`your_php_user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/killall node`

note: you have a space between `/usr/bin/` and `sudo`

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I have added that line to the sudoers file and it allows me to use the sudo command in terminal without having to type a password, but it still won't work on the webpage. Im not sure if i am using the right path to be able to use sudo. Do I first have to specify the path to sudo and then the path for killall? something like this- { exec('/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/killall node'); } That isn't working for me but should it be something like that?

Comment: have you tried to display the name of the user running the webserver ? ( echo \`whoami\`; )